# How to execute terminal command via php script

Tags: linux, php, sudo

I have a php script that I need to run a linux terminal command. My issue is that I need to run this as sudo but its not working. I have done VISUDO and added / disabled as follows:

```
asterisk ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/cmd.php
Defaults!/usr/sbin/cmd.php !requiretty
#Defaults    requiretty
#Defaults   !visiblepw
```

But I'm getting this error in apache logs "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified". FYI Apache is running as user asterisk and its Centos 6. I'm stuck now so reaching out.

Thanks

Comment: Is the command you are trying to run exactly "/usr/sbin/cmd.php"? I had problems in the past when I started it with php or added nice. Oh and did you get any errors in the auth.log?

Comment: I'm simply doing 'service asterisk stop' to check the concept. I checked secure logs and its showing "sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [asterisk]"

Comment: Hum I think my asterisk user has a password, what is best practice for this now?

Comment: Oh... with visudo you are supposed to specify the command you want to run and not the script that is running it

Comment: asterisk ALL = NOPASSWD: service asterisk stop

Comment: Ok, I have tried to do that change but I get "visudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 11 <<<"

Comment: The command has parameters. Maybe you could try creating an alias in sudo or alternatively a script for example /usr/local/bin/asterisk-stop.sh and use that for the command so it doesn't have parameters.

Comment: Ok I created a .sh script and added service asterisk stop. I also updated visduo with this script and I'm getting them same error 'auth could not idetify password for asterisk'.

Comment: Needing to run a shell command as root from inside PHP is a smell that you're doing something you really shouldn't be.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Your asterisk account not have shell login. sudo user must have shell login. Check it in /etc/passwd. If nologin, it means thar no access to shell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check asterisk API, it's call AMI (Asterisk Management Interface)
https://github.com/marcelog/PAMI